# Is it possible to calculate the volume of a point cloud using principal eigenvalues from PCA?

Tags: pca, python

Assume I have a point cloud in $\mathbf{R}^N$ and we take the $N$ principal component eigenvalues: $\lambda_1 , ... , \lambda_N$.

Does $\prod_i \lambda_i$ represent the effective volume surrounding the point cloud?

For example consider this random 3D data 200 point cloud:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from matplotlib import pyplot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull


X=np.random.normal(0, 1, (200, 3))
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(X)
lambdas=pca.explained_variance_

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:,2])
hull = ConvexHull(X)

print(np.prod(lambdas), lambdas)
print(hull.volume)
```

Which gives the following results:
$\sqrt {\det{XX'}}$: `0.959663480711`
volume of convex hull: `67.221497558671`

[image]

1. Why is the volume of the convex hull almost `75` bigger than $\prod_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i$?
2. How can I calculate the minimal ellipsoid that contains all/most of the points? When I say most I mean give some percentage $\alpha$ (e.g. 90%) find the volume of an ellipsoid that contains 90% of the points.

Comment: Volume is $\sqrt{\det X'X}$ where X is the n-dim. centered data cloud. Therefore...

Comment: @ttnphns what do you mean by centers data cloud?

Comment: Columns (variables) of the dataset are centered (column mean is subtracted).

Comment: @ttnphns the determinant will most probably vanish. Isn't it?

Comment: Why? What do you mean? The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues - of what you spoke in the question.

Comment: @ttnphns you are right. So basically this is the volume. But the dimensions don't work for me.

Comment: @ttnphns also how comes the volume of the convex hull is much larger than the determinant

Comment: The volume of the convex hull of a multivariate cloud is typically larger than the volume of a multuvariate cloud itself. Two figures - the cloud and its convex hull - can be very different size. Imagine, for example, a pair of outliers on one side od a cloud - the convex hull immediately bounces up in size.

Comment: @ttnphns as you can see the volume of the convex hull is 100x bigger.

Comment: How did you compute the hull's volume? It could be defined by less cardinality (i.e. number of landmark points) than the number of data points.

Comment: @ttnphns used the python code above.

Comment: Please provide us with a definition or an explanation of what you mean by "effective volume surrounding the point cloud."  As far as the question about convex hulls goes, take a look in *one* dimension: the answer should be much easier to see.

Comment: @whuber a volume of ellipsoid that will wrap most of the data points.

Comment: But what does "most of" mean?  If you want a quantitative answer you need to supply a quantitative description.  Note that the minimum-volume ellipsoid to contain a specified fraction of all points usually is *not* any of the possible solutions you have mentioned: it likely won't even be concentric with the point cloud and won't share any of its principal axes.

Comment: @whuber the minimal ellipsoid that contains all the data points.

Comment: If that really is your question, then you must edit your post to state it.  Otherwise people will answer the vague question that currently exists and the resulting confusion will be unhelpful.

Comment: @whuber I just want to calculate the minimal volume that contains all the data points.

Comment: Then the answer to your question as stated is no, it is not possible to find that minimal volume--either of the ellipsoid or convex hull--by means of the PCA.  It's done a totally different way!  But that's not a very productive outcome, is it?  Please think a little about how to formulate a clear, unambiguous, answerable question whose replies will be helpful to you.  Some advice about how to go about doing that is available in our [help].

Comment: @whuber what does the volume $\sqrt{\det X'X}$ represent?

Comment: It is related to an ellipsoid that describes the second moments of inertia of the cloud.  Most of the points--the vast majority of them, in high dimensions--will lie outside that ellipsoid, not inside it.  That ellipsoid has obvious uses for covariance-based analyses.  The minimal-volume enclosing ellipsoid is more obscure but plays a fundamental role in the design of experiments.  It is much harder to compute (although optimal algorithms are known).  Thus, both concepts are important but they are fundamentally different.